# How can i increase speed for loading of google maps embeded on site?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, xhtml, google-maps

Are there any javascripts or other method which can decrease loading time of google maps?
Google maps are added by iframe code.

**Update: 12 FEB 2010**

Can any jquery plugin be useful for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:
[Using Static Maps to Speed Up Your Dynamic Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/static+js.html)

Answer (score 2):

Is it just base maps with no markers causing an extended load time? Maybe a little more elaboration on the exact problem would be helpful, a stab in the dark here - do your maps have a lot of markers? Just assuming this would be contributing to the load time, anyhow, this [article](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Google maps are usually fast.
One possible reason to make it really slow is when you have a JS debugger open.

The old versions of Firefox + Firebug(FF < 3.6 & FB < 1.5) were terrible for that. Both new versions does not suffer it anymore.